# Is it possible to change my residence permit for study preparation to a work visa?

Tags: germany, working-visas, brazilian-citizens

I'm in the following situation. I'm Brazilian and I've come to Germany to study. Currently I possess the **residence permit for study preparation**. This week I've received an offer (I didn't look for a job - they got in touch with me) from a big company in the IT field to join their team. I already have the contract in hand!

Based on the salary, I would be able to apply for a Blue card but I don't meet the higher study degree that is required.

My only option would be applying for a normal full time work permit, but I would like to know if it is possible to do this? That is to change from my current visa to a full time work permit.

Comment: This sounds like a case where the following will apply: [Residence permit for qualified skilled workers with vocational training - Services - Dienstleistungen - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/305304/en/). Especially in the area of IT professions, the employer has a great deal to say as to whether you fullfill the needed qualifications.

Comment: Since I would assume that residence permit for study preparation is issued based on the same paragraph of immigration law as residence permit for study itself, the question is really a duplicate of another one: [Is it possible to change from a Student Visa to a Work Visa in Germany?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/19707/is-it-possible-to-change-from-a-student-visa-to-a-work-visa-in-germany)