# Can I still study on a work permit in Germany?

Tags: germany, student-visa, german-citizens, work-permit

I am about to complete my nursing training in 6 months and am currently on an apprenticeship Visa (non-EU citizen) in Germany. Having begun my masters (student visa) and later switched it to an apprenticeship, I am ready to complete my masters or start a new masters, but I don't want to be on a student visa again. Is there a possibility to study if I am on a work visa, as there are prospects of a job (work permit), or would that contradict the situation? I believe being on a student visa would limit me on the number of hours I can work.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but in some fields, there may be exemptions from limits on working hours. The medical field is very possibly one of those areas - if there are any at all. You might want to look into that.

Comment: You can find a lot of relevant information in the comments to one of my answers: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19837/13223